# jQuery dataTables not loaded on single div?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a div and three button. Based on button click, columns in datatable changes.
Here is mycode

```
  $('#impfamilydatatable').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
    "bDestroy": true,
    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 90, -1], [15, 30, 90, "All"]],
  });
```

button-1 having 3 columns in datatable and 2,3-having 4 columns

If I first clicked on button1 then dataTable works fine,but for other two buttons datatable not loaded.
If I first clicked on  button-2 datatable loaded ,then for button-3 also ,but not for button. I concluded that if no of column changes in table then only this problem raises.

Is there any solution for this?

`$('#impfamilydatatable').dataTable().fnDestroy();` (and i also tried)

```
   var a="";
   if(a !="") a.fnDestroy();
   a = $('#impfamilydatatable').dataTable({
        "aaSorting": [[ 1, "desc" ]],
        "bDestroy": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "aLengthMenu": [[15, 30, 90, -1], [15, 30, 90, "All"]],
   });
```

but none of this worked

Comment: post the click event function.

Comment: it is ajax call and respose comes to  a coomon method  where this this  datatable building

Comment: Since that I suggest you remove : "bDestroy": true, and every time you click the button, destroy the datatables and creat it again.

Comment: How did you destroy the datatables?

Comment: tableobj.fnDestroy();

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27237/discussion-between-anilhoney-and-oqjf)